# How can I edit parameters in my code with user input?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to take data input by the user and change two parameters (using the input) in my code template. After which I want to copy that template with the updated parameters onto an existing module.

My code accesses a website and scrapes data. After which I take a value in my data and put it into specific cells. Now, my code has to access different urls and put the data into a different cell each time, which are the two parameters I am trying to change.

Is there a way to create a code that is more user-friendly? Whereby you do not have to access the code editor to change these parameters but instead use an input box for the user to provide info?

I've not been able to find any methods that can take user input and change the code according to the input.

Code template

```vb
IE.navigate "First Parameter i have to change(URL OF SITE I am getting my value from)"
IE.Visible = True
Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Loop

Set HTMLDoc = IE.document
Set HTMLTable = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("table")(8)

rownum = 101
For Each HTMLRow In HTMLTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
    rownum = rownum + 1: ColNum = 1
    For Each HTMLCell In HTMLRow.Children
        Cells(rownum, ColNum) = HTMLCell.innerText
        ColNum = ColNum + 1
    Next
Next

'Paste values
Range("B125").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("Second parameter i have to change(Specific cell i am pasting my value on").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

I want the macro to copy the template with the updated parameters in this code.

```vb
Sub Get_Surrender_Values()

    Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLTables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLCell As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim rownum As Long, ColNum As Integer

End sub
```

Comment: A form might work better for this.  A series of InputBox dialogs isn't always user-friendly.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Actually yes, that would be a better idea. If it is only 2 parameters to ask for input boxes might do. If it is more parameters I would definitely go for the user form.

Comment: If building the user form is too much, an easy way out is to just have the user type the parameters into some named ranges on an excel sheet. Your macro can then refer to those named ranges when feeding parameters into your subs/functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually copying code is no good idea. Instead make your code more generic and change it in a way so it can take parameters:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Get_Surrender_Values(ByVal URL As String, ByVal Destination As Range)
    Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLTables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLCell As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim rownum As Long, ColNum As Integer

    IE.navigate URL
    IE.Visible = True
    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    
    Loop
    
    Set HTMLDoc = IE.document
    Set HTMLTable = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("table")(8)
    
    rownum = 101
    For Each HTMLRow In HTMLTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        rownum = rownum + 1: ColNum = 1
        For Each HTMLCell In HTMLRow.Children
            Cells(rownum, ColNum) = HTMLCell.innerText
            ColNum = ColNum + 1
        Next
    Next

    'Paste values
    Range("B125").Copy 'specify which worksheet this range is in!
    Destination.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End sub
```

Then call it like

```
Get_Surrender_Values URL:="http://www.google.de", Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("A1")
```

Or with input boxes like

```
Public Sub Example()
    ' ask for URL
    Dim ReturnURL As Variant
    ReturnURL = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="What is the URL?", Type:=2)
    If VarType(ReturnURL) = vbBoolean And ReturnURL = False Then 
        ' user pressed cancel
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' ask for destination cell
    Dim ReturnDestination As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ReturnDestination = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select a destination cell on the worksheet and press OK", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If ReturnDestination Is Nothing Then
        ' user pressed cancel
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' submit parameters to your procedure to get it from the website
    Get_Surrender_Values Url:=ReturnURL, Destination:=ReturnDestination
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. What im trying to achieve is with each set of inputs that the user gives, it builds onto my code. If the user inputs (website1,b51) as its first set of inputs and inputs (website2,b71) as its second set of inputs afterwards. I want the code to navigate to website1 ,input the value in b51 and then navigate to website2 , input the value from website2 into b71. Im still a complete novice with VBA so please forgive me if  going about it incorrectly.